# Can nginx generate primitive responses on its own?

Tags: nginx

For debugging purposes, I'd like my nginx to return a simple response when I try to request a specific URL. For example:

```
Hello, friend! You've connected successfully! Your IP address is 1.2.3.4.
```

The IP address is important, otherwise I could use a static file.

In addition, I don't want to use external processes for generating the response - no (F)CGI, proxy, whatever. It should be NGINX itself, so I can test it in isolation.

So far, I haven't found a module that could do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the below Nginx server configs

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    location /health {
      return 200 'Hi From Nginx $remote_addr';
    }
}
```

```
$> curl http://127.0.0.1/health
Hi From Nginx 172.28.0.1
```